# Is there an easy way to search Snippets in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I find that my collection of snippets has grown far beyond what can be managed by assigning a Category and Name. "I know I wrote this code before, it's probably in one of these three categories but it definitely hit table T and used function F; should my time be spent clicking thru each likely category and dragging out each snippet, reinventing it, or searching the snippets.xml?" is a conversation I have with myself far too often.

I tend to copy the snippet body into the tag so I can hover and see some of what's in there but still, being able to actually search the snippets (like we can do with SQL History) would be amazing. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way today.

I'm happy to log an enhancement request on your behalf for that feature.

In the meantime, maybe consider trying the Code Templates instead?

You can 'search' either by the name of your code template, or by the first word of the code template 'source'

type the word, and then ctrl+enter to bring up the list of 'hits'

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Where would I be able to track enhancement requests? 
It looks like "Oracle SQL Developer Exchange" [https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=43135:1::::::] may have faded away and I'm not sure where people moved to.
I use Code Templates for my simpler queries and didn't know that the 'Completion Insight' would also list Templates by their first characters. I may not be able to put comments as the first word, but I can at least slop in an extra keyword to help me and remove it later. This sorta helps!

Comment: With my oracle support, you need a support contract